# Lemma 21.2 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The Sequence Lemma

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Here is Lemma 21.2 (The Sequence Lemma) in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be a topological space; let $A \subset X$. If there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$; the converse holds if $X$ is metrizable.

I think I understand the statement and proof of this lemma.

Now my question is, can we give an example of a (non-metrizable) topological space in which although a point $x \in \overline{A}$, there is no sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$?

And, in a topological space $X$, if, for every $A \subset X$ and  for every point  $x \in \overline{A}$, there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$, then can we guarantee that the space $X$ is necessarily metrizable?

Comment: You would need a space that isn't first countable. Uncountable ordinals would be the first thing that I would try. Also your second question seems to be asking if first countability implies metrizability, which isn't true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the box topology $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, it is not metrizable. Consider the subset $A$ which consists of elements that has all coordinates postitive. Then $x=(0,0,0,...)\in \overline{A}$, but there is no sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$.

---

For your second question, consider the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$. If $A$ is finite, then $A=\overline{A}$, in this case, we obviously have the desired sequence. If $A$ is infinite, then $\overline{A} = \mathbb{R}$, note that in cofinite topology, a sequence consisting of infinitely many distinct points converges to every point, so again, your desired property is satisfied. But this space not metrizable, for it is not even Hausdorff.

Comment: My edit was for a typo ("everypoint') and to change "consists" to "consisting"..... The computer prefers "co-finite" to "cofinite" but it's not in charge.

Comment: @pisco  In your first example, how can you say that  there is no sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$? Would you explain?

Comment: @BijanDatta   Let $x_i = (x_{i,1},x_{i,2},\cdots)$ be a sequence in $A$. Then the neighbourhood $(-x_{1,1}, x_{1,1})\times (-x_{2,2},x_{2,2})\times \cdots$ of $(0,0,\cdots)$ contains none of $x_i$.

Comment: @pisco Right. I've got it.