# Does the sequence lemma hold for Hausdorff?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Munkres Topology: Sequence Lemma

> Let $X$ be a topological space; let $A \subset X$. If there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$; the converse holds if $X$ is metrizable.

This lemma has been asked about before. [Lemma 21.2 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The Sequence Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452806/lemma-21-2-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-the-sequence-lemma)

My question is about changing "metrizable" with "Hausdorff". I found a class where in a [homework problem set](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~guillou/F17/551HW4.pdf), it says "This is an example of a non-Hausdorff space in which the sequence lemma holds." The saying says to me that the class has a version of the sequence lemma that holds for Hausdorff and then there's an example where the sequence lemma holds for something they would not expect, which is non-Hausdorff. (Another explanation is that the example is non-metrizable and then it is additionally pointed out that the example is also non-Hausdorff.) I hope that the version is exactly the same as the one above except for changing "metrizable" with "Hausdorff". (I cannot find anything of the sort in [Week 4](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~guillou/F17/551Notes-Week4.pdf) or [Notes](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~guillou/F17/551Notes.pdf) for whole class.)

I have attempted a proof but it has some resemblance to the proof for metrizable spaces. I am choosing to not type up this proof fearing it is wrong because I have somehow assumed metrization.

Comment: What's really important is not Hausdorfness, it's first-countability (definition 10.13 in the notes you linked to, right after the sequence lemma) : see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725681/if-x-in-overlinea-implies-x-is-the-limit-of-a-sequence-in-a-for-all-a

Comment: @ArnaudD. So not all Hausdorff is first countable? So why say "non-Hausdorff"? Thank you!

Comment: You mean in the exercise? I guess the point was to emphasize that the sequence lemma could be true even in a non-Hausdorff space, and that ultimately Hausdorfness and the sequence lemma are actually independent.

Answer (score 2):

You need first countability for this to work. So the statement

> If $X$ is Hausdorff, then $x\in \bar{A}$ implies that there is a sequence in $A$ converging to $X$.

is not true.

For example, consider $X=\omega_{1}+1=\{0,1,\ldots,\omega_{0},\omega_{0}+1,\ldots,\omega_{1}\}$ with the order topology (where $\omega_{1}$ is the union of all countable ordinals, i.e. the first uncountable ordinal). This is a Hausdorff space. The closure of $A=\{ x\in \omega_{1}+1 \mid x<\omega_{1} \}$ is then $X$, so $\omega_{1}\in \bar{A}$. But we cannot find a sequence in $A$ converging to $\omega_{1}$ (for cardinality reasons).

Comment: A very nice, bare bones counterexample.

Comment: @LeeMosher So not all Hausdorff is first countable? So why say "non-Hausdorff"? Thank you!

Comment: No, not alll Hausdorff spaces are first countable. Take your favorite non-first countable metric space (any metric space is Hausdorff as we can separate distinct point by disjoint balls)

Answer (score 1):

The "sequence lemma" ($x \in \overline{A}$ iff there is a sequence from $A$ converging to $x$) holds exactly in the class of [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space). All first countable spaces are sequential (so all metrisable ones are).

A sequential space can be Hausdorff but need not be. These are independent of each other: the line with two origins is not Hausdorff and sequential. The co-countable topology on the reals is not Hausdorff and not sequential. Any metric space is Hausdorff and sequential and $\omega_1+1$ (or $\overline{S}_\Omega$) is not sequential but Hausdorff.